# Window Disappears While Performing a Drag-And-Drop in the Status Bar

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, window, xcode5

I'm making a Mac application, 10.9, Objective-C. The application stays in the Menu Bar (Status Bar) and when the user wants to use it, he/she can click the icon and a window comes up.

[image: This is how the status item looks like]

Now, I've changed the text of the infographic inside the application ("Click abd Select...."); earlier it was "Drag and Drop to Start".

I want to implement a drag-and-drop functionality, I've done that using a custom view; but the view (window) is not persistent. Everytime I select a file, this window disappears.

How do I make this window so that it does not disappear!

[image: Something like this.]

My window disappears when I click select a file to drop.

P.S.: I tried using the following code, but it didn't work

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[[self window]makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

[[self window]setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
```

Comment: What's the type of window?

Comment: Its a normal NSWindow, but, for adding the statusbar functionality, I've used this [OBMenuBarWindow](https://github.com/obolton/OBMenuBarWindow)